# Update Record from Previous Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

SQL Server 2008 R2

Have the table below:

```
Device       | DateOfSample|  Value
=================================
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-07|    0
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-08|    32
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-09|    30
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-10|    5
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-11|    29
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-12|    0
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-13|    57
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-14|    50
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-15|    0
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-16|    52
```

I need to update the value table to have the previous days value if it is 0 so that it looks like this:

```
Device       | DateOfSample|  Value
=================================
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-07|    0
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-08|    32
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-09|    30
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-10|    5
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-11|    29
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-12|    29
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-13|    57
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-14|    50
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-15|    50
Pump 1 Starts| 2020-07-16|    52
```

I don't want the first value in the table to change if it is 0, but any other 0 values need to be recorded as the same as the day before.

I've been trying to use Update Case, But I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

```
UPDATE #MaxValues
    SET Value = CASE
    WHEN m.Value = 0 THEN (
        SELECT m1.Value
        FROM #MaxValues m1
        WHERE m1.DateOfSample = DateAdd (Day, -1, (SELECT m2.DateOfSample FROM #MaxValues m2 WHERE Value = 0)))
    ELSE m.Value
    END
FROM #MaxValues AS m
```

All I'm getting is an error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_PumpStartAvg, Line 156
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I get why I'm getting the error, its because there are multiple locations in the table that have 0 and I'm trying to return all of them within the date selection statement. I just don't know how to get around this.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is an iterative process. At least I suppose it is. If a day's value is zero and the previous value is also zero, you probably want the value of the row prior to the previous one - if that isn't zero, too ;-) I don't know what stored procedures in SQL Server are capable of, so I cannot say whether they could help here. You could run through the values in a recursive query and then update the zero-value rows with the values found. But well, I guess, if this ain't millions of rows, I'd simply select all rows in an app, loop through them and issue the few (?) updates necessary from there.

Comment: @MarkUnderwood . . . Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Comment: Using an unsupported version, because that is the version that the software package requires. We are moving away from it, but cannot get rid of it just yet. Hoping to do away with it except for a lookup before the end of the year.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, think the simplest and most efficient approach is window function and an updatable CTE:

```
with cte as (
    select value, lag(value) over(partition by devince order by dateOfSample) lag_value
    from mytable 
)
update cte set value = lag_value
where value = 0 and lag_value is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Device] VARCHAR(16)
   ,[DateOfSample] DATE
   ,[Value] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Device], [DateOfSample], [Value])
VALUES ('Pump 1 Starts', '2020-07-07', 0)
      ,('Pump 1 Starts', '2020-07-08', 32)
      ,('Pump 1 Starts', '2020-07-09', 30)
      ,('Pump 1 Starts', '2020-07-10', 5)
      ,('Pump 1 Starts', '2020-07-11', 29)
      ,('Pump 1 Starts', '2020-07-12', 0)
      ,('Pump 1 Starts', '2020-07-13', 57)
      ,('Pump 1 Starts', '2020-07-14', 50)
      ,('Pump 1 Starts', '2020-07-15', 0)
      ,('Pump 1 Starts', '2020-07-16', 52);

UPDATE DS1
SET [Value] = DS2.[Value]
FROM @DataSource DS1
INNER JOIN @DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[Device] = DS2.[Device]
    AND DS1.[DateOfSample] = DATEADD(DAY, 1, DS2.[DateOfSample])
WHERe DS1.[Value] = 0


SELECT *
FROM @DataSource
ORDER BY [Device]
        ,[DateOfSample];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find previous date using DateTime function (Datediff).Try this query,please:

```
Update t2
Set t2.Value=t1.Value
FROM Table t1
left join Table t2
on DATEDIFF(dd,t1.DateofSample,t2.DateofSample)=1
and t2.device=t1.device
and t2.Value=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "previous row" you mean the "previous date", then a `join` is the best solution:

```
update t
    set Value = coalesce(t1.Value, 0)
from t left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.DateofSample = dateadd(day, -1, t.DateofSample);
```

If by "previous row" you really mean the previous row even when there are gaps, then GMB's solution using `lag()` -- which requires SQL Server 2012 -- is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help.

I ended up solving the problem by building the original table differently. Thereby eliminating the need to solve the problem at all.